# Google maps API - how to get nearest place name from coordinates, ignoring non specific results

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, google-maps-api-3

For a given set of coordinates, how can I find out the name of the nearest place ignoring non specific results such as unnamed roads?
Currently I am using the code below:

```
NSString *CompleteStringURL = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=25.75,-80.17&MyGoogleSDKAPIKey";
NSURL *wurl = [NSURL URLWithString:CompleteStringURL];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: wurl];

if (nil == data)
{
  NSLog(@"Error: Fail to get data");
}
else
{
  NSDictionary *jSONresult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
  NSArray *results = [jSONresult valueForKey:@"results"];
  NSArray *address_components = [[results valueForKey:@"address_components"] objectAtIndex: 0]; 
  NSString *short_name = [[address_components valueForKey:@"short_name"]objectAtIndex:0];
  NSLog(@"short_name = %@", short_name);
}
```

First clarification needed: am I correct assuming that the nearest results would be shown first, at the first index of the `address_components` array?
In this case using `[[results valueForKey:@"address_components"] objectAtIndex: 0]` should give me the nearest place. Right?

Now my problem: I want to show only the name of the closest point of interest (regardless of its type), but I want to filter out all the non specific results... To be clear, the name of buildings, restaurants, museums, schools, petrol stations are fine, but I want to ignore all the unnamed roads or places.
Which filters could I use? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1)you can use google maps api

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=true_or_false

2) pass your lat , long values to above url

3) you get json response parse for key value formatted_address

4) you get near place you are looking for.